# Bitmap on ViewPager causes memory leak

Tags: android, image, android-viewpager, out-of-memory

I'm using a ViewPager with PagerAdapter to show a view that contains two ImageViews (one with big image and on with a small icon) and a TextView. As you "turn the pages" on the ViewPager, the heap keeps on growing until it crashes on OutOfMemoryError (192MB).
The GC is unable to free the space. Even when I switch activities, the heap keeps its size.
Here are parts of the adapter, please let me know if you need other parts of the code..
The destroyItem method was suppose to clear the view and free the memory, but it doesn't.
"TicketViewHolder.image" is the ImageView which holds the somewhat large image.
The next step would be to rescale the images, but that's not the main issue here.

```
private class TicketViewHolder {
    private TextView name;
    private ImageView image;
    private ImageView vSign;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    TicketViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.ticket_page, container, false);
    holder = new TicketViewHolder();
    holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ticket_name);
    holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ticket_image);
    holder.vSign = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ticket_v);

    Word word = getItem(position);
    holder.name.setText(word.getName());

    holder.image.setImageResource(word.getImageID());
    holder.image.setOnClickListener(onImageClickListener);

    holder.image.setTag(position);
    holder.vSign.setTag(position);
    holder.vSign.setOnClickListener(onPositiveProductionClickListener);

    if (word.isCorrect()) {
        holder.vSign.setImageResource(R.drawable.v_green);
    } else {
        holder.vSign.setImageResource(R.drawable.v_red);
    }

    container.addView(view, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    jazzyViewPager.setObjectForPosition(view, position);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object obj) {
    Log.d("DESTROY", "destroying view at position " + position);
    View view = (View) obj;
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView(view);
    view = null;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how this works, but does it affect anything that you, in your call to inflate, use container and then later add it to the container again? does it add the item twice?

Comment: It doesn't. I'm not sure if it makes a difference but I'm using a custom ViewPager. the inflate creates the view and the container.addview is putting the view inside the custom viewpager. anyway, this is not what's causing the memory leak..

Comment: What do you do with the TicketViewHolder? I don't see where you keep it alive. Could it be that you keep the holder alive somewhere and therefore leak memory, or could it be holder.image.setOnClickListener(onImageClickListener); that keeps it alive?

Comment: Not sure I understand, I keep it in a private class inside the PagerAdapter and address it from instantiateItem method. At first I clean it (TicketViewHolder holder = null;) and then create a new instance. just like in listview, it suppose to recycle with scroll..

Comment: I checked what you said about the OnClickListener, and it's not it. I removed the setOnClickListener and the heap keeps on growing..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I thought it was a general problem but apparently not. It is related to the custom ViewPager I'm using - [JazzyViewPager](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager), and there I found the [solution](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager/issues/6).

Answer (score 1):

try this code in your ViewPagerAdapter class

```
   private int getPagesBack() {
        return currentPosition - 3;
    }

    private int getPagesForward() {
        return currentPosition + 3;
    }

    private boolean canDestroy(int position) {
        return !(position > getPagesBack() && position < getPagesForward());
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    if(canDestroy(position)){
            Log.d(TAG, "destorying position: " + position);
            View v = (View) object;
            container.removeView((View) object);
    }
    }
```